# Bug in Internet Explorer 7 element.getAttribute method

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

I'm implementing a length counter on textareas for a website (twitter style). I'm using the code found here http://www.codefromjames.com/wordpress/?p=15 but seems not to work in IE7.
I've traced the issue to the check of the attribute "maxlength" in an element. It expects it to be null if the attribute is not found, but IE7 returns a number (which I guess is the maximum length allowed by the browser or by the HTML standard, I don't know).
Here's an example you can try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="es" lang="es">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="test"></input>
  </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
var element = document.getElementById("test");
alert(element.getAttribute("maxlength"));
</script>
</html>
```

Try executing this on IE7 and you'll find out it gives a number instead of null.

Exact version of IE7 is 7.0.5703.13

Should I consider this a IE7 bug or is it working as expected?

Cheers!

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h5qh3/.

Comment: In IE 7 it shows numerical value `2147483647` purely IE bug

Comment: I have figured out this issue. For `<input>` it gives the numeric value as I mentioned. But for `<textarea>` it gives `null` value. And the link you gave `http://www.codefromjames.com/wordpress/?p=15 ` in this example `<textarea>` is being used instead of `<input>`

Comment: I get null in IE8 and a numerical value 2147483647 in IE7 mode in IE8 - The largest positive value of a signed integer on a 32 bit operating system and a double mercienne prime...

Comment: Yes, it seems it doesn't work with <input> tags. It's strange because if you look for element.attributes["maxlength"] in an input element, it returns undefined even if the attribute is there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `element.attributes.maxLength.specified` to find out whether maxLength is indeed user-specified.

```
var element = document.getElementById('test');
var maxLength, defaultLength = 100;

if (element.attributes.maxLength && element.attributes.maxLength.specified) {
 maxLength = element.attributes.maxLength.nodeValue || defaultLength;
} else {
 maxLength = defaultLength;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a nice tradeoff to make it IE7 compatible. Thanks